Laravel Validation can not read required field
Laravel fails to read the required validation for my array,
This is my function for pushing data to machineryRows array:
const addmachineryRow=()=>{

    machineryRows.value.push({
        stock_SNW_id:'',
        machinery_id:'',
        serial_no:'',
        tag_no:'',
        unit_id:'',
        mfg_date:'',
        exp_date:'',
        machine_status_id:'',
        project_id:'',
        qnt:'',
        price:'',
        total:0,
        description:'',
        issues:[]

    });
}

This is my function to push data inside issues array of machineryRows array:
function addIssue(machineryRow) {

    machineryRow.issues.push({
        stock_SNW_id:'',
        issue_solution:'',
        description: ''
    });
}

This is my template and fields:
<div class="row  w-full  mt-4 ">

                            <div
                                class="col-md-12"
                                v-for="(machineryRow, index) in machineryRows" :key="index"
                            >
                                <AppFieldset :legendText="Lang.get('lang.Hospital Equipment ')+(index+1)" :legendClass="legendClass">
                                    <div class="top-0 end-0 position-absolute">
                                        <AppButton
                                            type="danger"
                                            btn-sm
                                            @click="removeMachineryRow(index)"
                                        >
                                            <i class="fe fe-x"></i>
                                        </AppButton>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6" >
                                        <FormLabel>{{ Lang.get('lang.Machinery Name ') }}</FormLabel>
                                        <DropdownMachineriesHospitalBased v-model="machineryRow.machinery_id"
                                                                          @select="(option) => setSelectedDetail(option, index)" />

                                        <InputError name="machinery"/>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                        <FormLabel>Serial No</FormLabel>
                                        <FormInput  v-model="machineryRow.serial_no" readonly/>
                                        <InputError name="serial_no"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                        <FormLabel>Tag No</FormLabel>
                                        <FormInput  v-model="machineryRow.tag_no" readonly/>
                                        <InputError name="tag_no"/>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                        <FormLabel>Manufacture Date</FormLabel>
                                        <FormInput  v-model="machineryRow.mfg_date" readonly/>
                                        <InputError name="assessment_date"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                        <FormLabel>Expiry Date</FormLabel>
                                        <FormInput  v-model="machineryRow.exp_date" readonly/>
                                        <InputError name="assessment_date"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3" >
                                        <FormLabel>{{ Lang.get('lang.Project ') }}</FormLabel>
                                        <FormInput v-model="machineryRow.project_id" readonly/>
                                        <InputError name="project"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                        <FormLabel>Quantity</FormLabel>
                                        <FormInput  v-model="machineryRow.qnt"  readonly/>
                                        <InputError name="quantity"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3" >
                                        <FormLabel>{{ Lang.get('lang.Unit ') }}</FormLabel>
                                        <FormInput v-model="machineryRow.unit_id" readonly/>
                                        <InputError name="machinery"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                        <FormLabel>Price</FormLabel>
                                        <FormInput  v-model="machineryRow.price" readonly/>
                                        <InputError name="price"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                        <FormLabel>Total</FormLabel>
                                        <FormInput v-model="machineryRow.total" readonly/>
                                        <InputError name="total"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3" style="width:500px">
                                        <FormLabel>{{ Lang.get('lang.Machinery Status ') }}</FormLabel>
                                        <DropdownMachine_Status v-model="machineryRow.machine_status_id"/>
                                        <InputError name="machinery_status"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                        <FormLabel>Description</FormLabel>
                                        <FormInput v-model="machineryRow.description" />
                                        <InputError name="description"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div v-for="(issue, issueIndex) in machineryRow.issues" :key="index" class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <AppFieldset :legendText="Lang.get('lang.Issues')" :legendClass="legendClass">
                                        <div class="top-0 end-0 position-absolute">
                                            <AppButton
                                                type="danger"
                                                btn-sm
                                                @click.prevent="removeIssue(machineryRow, issueIndex)"
                                            >
                                                <i class="fe fe-x"></i>
                                            </AppButton>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                            <FormLabel>{{ Lang.get('lang.Issue ') }}{{ issueIndex + 1 }}</FormLabel>
                                            <FormInput v-model="issue.issue_solution"/>
                                            <InputError name="issue"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                            <FormLabel>{{ Lang.get('lang.Description ') }}{{ issueIndex + 1 }}</FormLabel>
                                            <FormInput v-model="issue.description" />
                                            <InputError name="issue"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </AppFieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                        <AppButton type="outline-danger" @click.prevent="addIssue(machineryRow)">
                                            <i class="fe fe-plus"></i>{{ Lang.get('lang.Add Issue') }}
                                        </AppButton>
                                    </div>
                                </AppFieldset>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <AppButton
                                    type="outline-secondary"
                                    @click.prevent="addmachineryRow"
                                >
                                    <i class="fe fe-plus">Add Hospital Equipment</i>
                                </AppButton>
                            </div>
                        </div>

This is store function inside controller:
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $userID = auth()->user()->id;

            $request->request->add(['createdby' => $userID, 'updatedby' => $userID]);

            $attrs = $request->validate([
                'maintenance_reports' => [
                    'hospital_id' => ['required'],
                    'year_id' => ['required'],
                    'month_id' => ['required'],
                    'assessment_date' => ['required', 'date_format:Y-m-d'],
                    'maktoob_no' => ['nullable'],
                    'maktoob_date' => ['required', 'date_format:Y-m-d'],
                    'status_id' => ['required'],
                    'remarks' => ['nullable'],
                    'description' => ['nullable'],
                    'createdby' => ['required'],
                    'updatedby' => ['required'],
                ],

                'staff__performances' => [
                    '*.staff_id' => ['required'],
                    '*.staff_role_id' => ['required'],
                    '*.description' => ['nullable'],
                    '*.createdby' => ['required'],
                    '*.updatedby' => ['required'],
                ],

                'hospital_maintenance_details' => [
                    '*.maintenance_master_id' => ['required', 'numeric'],
                    '*.stock_SNW_id' => ['required', 'numeric'],
                    '*.description' => ['nullable', 'string'],
                    '*.issues' => ['required', 'array', 'min:1'],
                    '*.createdby' => ['required'],
                    '*.updatedby' => ['required'],
                ],
                'stock_serial_machine_statuses' => [
                    '*.stock_serialNoWise_id' => ['sometimes', 'numeric'],
                    '*.machine_status_id' => ['sometimes', 'numeric'],
                    '*.description' => ['nullable', 'string'],
                    '*.createdby' => ['sometimes'],
                    '*.updatedby' => ['sometimes'],
                ],

                'bio_md_maintenance_dealers' => [
                    '*.stock_SNW_id' => ['sometimes', 'numeric'],
                    '*.stock_SNW_issue_id' => ['sometimes', 'numeric'],
                    '*.description' => ['nullable', 'string'],
                    '*.createdby' => ['sometimes'],
                    '*.updatedby' => ['sometimes'],
                ]



            ]);


            $attrs['maintenance_reports']['createdby'] = $userID;
            $attrs['maintenance_reports']['updatedby'] = $userID;
            $hospitalEquipmentMaster = MaintenanceReport::create($attrs['maintenance_reports']);

            $staffPerformancesData = $attrs['staff__performances'];
            foreach ($staffPerformancesData as $staffPerformance) {

                $staffPerformance['createdby'] = $userID;
                $staffPerformance['updatedby'] = $userID;

                $hospitalEquipmentMaster->staffPerformances()->create($staffPerformance);
            }


            $hospitalEquipmentDetailsData = $attrs['hospital_maintenance_details'];
            $serialMachineStatus = $attrs['stock_serial_machine_statuses'];


            foreach ($hospitalEquipmentDetailsData as $hospitalEquipmentDetail) {

                $hospitalEquipmentDetail['createdby'] = $userID;
                $hospitalEquipmentDetail['updatedby'] = $userID;

 
                $serialMachineStatus = [

                    'stock_serialNoWise_id' => $hospitalEquipmentDetail['stock_SNW_id'],
                    'machine_status_id' => $hospitalEquipmentDetail['machine_status_id'],
                    'description' => $hospitalEquipmentDetail['description'],
                    'createdby' => $userID,
                    'updatedby' => $userID,
                ];

                $hospitalEquipmentMaster->transType()->create($serialMachineStatus);

                    foreach ($hospitalEquipmentDetail['issues'] as $issue) {
                        $serialMachineIssues = [
                            'stock_SNW_id' => $hospitalEquipmentDetail['stock_SNW_id'],
                            'issue_solution' => $issue['issue_solution'],
                            'description' => $issue['description'],
                            'createdby' => $userID,
                            'updatedby' => $userID,
                        ];

                        $createdIssue = $hospitalEquipmentMaster->issue()->create($serialMachineIssues);

                        $maintenanceDealer = [
                            'stock_SNW_id' => $hospitalEquipmentDetail['stock_SNW_id'],
                            'stock_SNW_issue_id' => $createdIssue->id,
                            'description' => $issue['description'],
                            'createdby' => $userID,
                            'updatedby' => $userID,
                        ];

                        $hospitalEquipmentMaster->maintenaceDealer()->create($maintenanceDealer);
                    }
                }

            DB::commit();
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Records added successfully']);
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();

            return response()->json(['message' => 'Error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }


    } 

In validation I have mentioned the the issues array inside 'hospital_maintenance_details' array is required should be array and at least have one element.
But if i don't pass the array or pass an empty array still the code works and does not throw any error.
this is save function in vue:
async function storeData() {

    clearErrorText();
    formProcessing.value = true;
    const postData = {
        maintenance_reports: formData.value,
        staff__performances: staffRows.value,
        hospital_maintenance_details: machineryRows.value,
        stock_serial_machine_statuses: statusData.value,
        // stock_serial_machine_issues: issues.value,
        bio_md_maintenance_dealers: maintenance_dealer.value,
    };
    await axios.post(route('maintenance-issue.store'), postData)
        .then(async (response) => {
            swal.fire({
                title: 'Success!',
                text: response.data.message ,
                icon: 'success',
            });
            setTimeout(() => {
                swal.close();
            },1500);
            formProcessing.value = false;
            formData.value = {
                hospital_id: '',
                year_id: '',
                month_id: '',
                assessment_date: '',
                maktoob_no:'',
                maktoob_date: '',
                status_id: '',
                description:'',


            };
            staffRows.value = [
                {
                    staff_id:'',
                    staff_role_id:'',
                    description:'',
                }
            ];
            machineryRows.value = [
                {
                    machinery_id:'',
                    serial_no:'',
                    tag_no:'',
                    unit_id:'',
                    mfg_date:'',
                    exp_date:'',
                    machine_status_id:'',
                    project_id:'',
                    qnt:'',
                    price:'',
                    total:0,
                    description:'',
                },
            ];


            await getMaintenanceIssues();
        })
        .catch ((e) => {
            swal.fire({
                title: 'Error!',
                text: e.response.data.message,
                icon: 'error',
            });
            if (e.response.status === 422) {
                const errors = e.response.data.errors;
                showErrors(errors);
            }

            formProcessing.value = false;
        });

}


Did you try adding "hospital_maintenance_details" => ["required"] ?

if a field in hospital_maintenance_details is defined as required it will automatically make the field required
